# Count the courses that are going on in a room currently passing the room, the start time, the end time, the date

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my request query :

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(shedule_line.id) AS total_available
FROM
    shedule_line
WHERE
    shedule_line.salle_id = :salle AND
    shedule_line.date = :date AND 
    (
        (shedule_line.start_at < :start_at AND shedule_line.end_at > :end_at) OR
        (shedule_line.start_at > :start_at AND shedule_line.end_at < :end_at) OR
        (shedule_line.start_at < :end_at) 
    );
```

This is my shedule_line table: 
[image: shedule_line_table]

I'll build the count of the courses that are going on in a room currently passing the room, the start time, the end time, the date.

Comment: With this query, I don't get the results I want. I need help please.
 for example : taking into account the data on the picture, if I tried with data like this: room(salle_id) = 2, start_at = 10: 00: 00, end_at = 20: 00: 00, date = 2020-02-10, I must receive 2 as total_available, but with the current request I receive 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
SELECT COUNT(sl.id) AS total_in_use
FROM shedule_line sl
WHERE sl.salle_id = :salle AND
      sl.date = :date AND 
      (sl.start_at < :end_at AND
       sl.end_at > :start_at
      );
```

Two time intervals overlap is one starts before the second ends, and the first ends after the first starts.

Comment: so this does not cover all case :  for example : taking into account the data on the picture, if I tried with data like this: room = 2, start_at = 10: 00: 00, end_at = 20: 00: 00,
date = 2020-02-10, I must receive 2 as total, but with the current request I receive 0

Comment: @instantech . . . This should count two overlaps for the situation you describe.

Comment: @instantech . . . It has always worked.  I didn't change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `total_available` 
FROM `shedule_line` 
WHERE `salle_id` = 2 
AND `date` = '2020-02-10' 
AND `start_at` BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '20:00:00' 
AND `end_at` BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '20:00:00';
```

**OR**

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `total_available` 
FROM `shedule_line` 
WHERE `salle_id` = 2 
AND `date` = '2020-02-10' 
AND `start_at` >= '10:00:00' 
AND `end_at` BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '20:00:00';
```

Check the result on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/135f5e/2)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(shedule_line.id) AS total_available  
FROM shedule_line  
WHERE shedule_line.salle_id = :salle AND shedule_line.date = :date
 AND (
    shedule_line.start_at < CAST(:end_at as time)
    AND shedule_line.end_at > CAST(:start_at as time)
 )OR 
(
  shedule_line.start_at > CAST(:end_at as time) 
  AND shedule_line.end_at > CAST(:start_at as time)
);
```

Finally I found this solution which works well. Thank you all.